# Help with declaring C++ structure, with a float array as one of its members

Tags: c++, arrays, structure, declaration

I was wondering if anyone could spot what is wrong with my structure declaration and use. At the moment I have a structure and wish to store float array as one of it's members.

#### My code:

```
struct Player{
float x[12];
float y[12];
float red,green,blue;
float r_leg, l_leg;
int poly[3];
bool up,down;
};
```

I then tried filling the struct:

```
float xcords[12] = {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1 };
float ycords[12] = {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1 };
Player player = {xcords,ycords,1,1,1,2,2,true,true};
```

#### Error:

```
1>.\template_with_console.cpp(35) : error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'float [12]' to 'float'
1>        There is no context in which this conversion is possible
1>.\template_with_console.cpp(35) : error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'float [12]' to 'float'
1>        There is no context in which this conversion is possible
```

Comment: Your struct has 10 fields, and you're only passing 9 items :)

Comment: Andy that's no problem, the last one just becomes zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arrays decay to pointer-to-first-element of the array in most contexts as is the case with `xcords` and `ycords`. You cannot initialize the struct like this. So, you have to initialize the members explicitly:

```
Player player = {
        {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1 }, // xcords
        {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1 }, // ycords
        1,1,1,                      // red, green, blue
        2,2,                        // right, left
        {0,1,2},                    // poly[3]   -- missing?          
        true,true};                 // up, down
```

You are also missing initializers for poly[3] if I understand correctly. Put in the appropriate values. Otherwise there will be default initialization -- is that what you want?

Comment: No: Copy Constructor and assignemnt operator work out of the box for this. No need to do un-nesacery work.

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
Player player = {{1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1 },
                 {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1 },
                 1,1,1,
                 2,2,
                 {},
                 true,true};
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're expecting the initialization to copy the elements of each array into your structure.  Try initializing the array elements in your structure individually, say with a `for` loop.

There is no "constructor" for a float array that will copy the elements of another array.

Comment: Yes, I am use to Java and Matlab, where all things are hidden and the world of programming is a nice and beautiful place. lol Thanks for all your help, this has answered my question excellently. Thankyou to you all!!! :-)